Can I have an NLA channel containing multiple armatures?
I've set up Animation retargeting with this tool: https://github.com/cgvirus/Simple-Retarget-Tool-Blender that uses blender's in-built bone constraints to have the bones of the new armature constrained to the poses of the old armature. (because this would be faster and more data compact when compared to generating entirely separate animations/actions for each alternate armature using this addon: https://github.com/Mwni/blender-animation-retargeting )
And when I was importing my blend file to Godot and I noticed that only the bone constraints that are within the same armature as the constrained bone are animated.
e.g. where the "target" armature is the same armature as the bone with this bone constraint:

The NLA editor (of which Godot pulls the animations from) seems to be tied to a specific armature, animations for "Armature Male [M]" channel do not affect animations for "Armature Short Female" channel:

And I don't want to merge the armatures into one object.
So can I have an NLA channel encompassing multiple armatures somehow or nah?
ty.
